# Is it possible to use variables with the 'DIALOG' and 'CONVERSATION' commands?

Tags: sql-server, schema, database-project

I've been able to setup my Visual Studio (2019) Database Project up and using database references fine for tables, stored procedures, views, etc.  They all seem to match up fine with the schema I've imported.  However, I can't seem to avoid errors when it comes to referencing the same database's contracts, types, services, etc.  When I reference the target database's service I have no issue (I assume this is because it accepts basic NVARCHAR strings versus a strongly-typed schema.

I've got the following example that just sends a message to another database's service.  I get the error: "SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[z_Queue_SendMessage] has an unresolved reference to object [@VariableName]" with @VariableName being all of the following: (@RequestMessageType, @BasicContract, @InitiatorService)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[z_Queue_SendMessage]
    @ProcedureName VARCHAR(1000) = 'Procedure', 
    @SubProcedureName VARCHAR(500) = 'SO', 
    @ProcedureType VARCHAR(200) = 'Delete', 
    @Inserted AS XML = NULL, 
    @Deleted AS XML = NULL
AS


DECLARE @InitDlgHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

DECLARE @RequestMsg NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Message XML;

DECLARE @RequestMessageType NVARCHAR(100) = '//$(WebDb)' + N'/Queue/RequestMessage'
DECLARE @InitiatorService NVARCHAR(100) = '//$(WebDb)' + N'/Queue/InitiatorService'
DECLARE @BasicContract NVARCHAR(100) = '//$(WebDb)' + N'/Queue/BasicContract'
DECLARE @TargetService NVARCHAR(100) = '//$(WebDb)' + N'/Queue/TargetService'


BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN DIALOG @InitDlgHandle
        FROM SERVICE [@InitiatorService] --Here
        TO SERVICE @TargetService
        ON CONTRACT [@BasicContract] --Here
        WITH
            ENCRYPTION = OFF;

SET @Message = (SELECT
                ProcedureName    = @ProcedureName,
                SubProcedureName = @SubProcedureName,
                ProcedureType    = @ProcedureType,
                Inserted         = @Inserted,
                Deleted          = @Deleted
            FOR XML PATH('Request'));

SEND ON CONVERSATION @InitDlgHandle
        MESSAGE TYPE [@RequestMessageType] --Here
        (@Message);

SELECT @Message AS SentRequestMsg;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Is there any way to format this so I don't get the error message without using Dynamic SQL?  It defeats the purpose if I can't confirm it matches the database schema by suppressing errors or using dynamic SQL instead.

Comment: `[@variable]` is never valid in that usage in any command as it refers an _identifier_ named "@variable". The `[..]` construct quotes any content, such as `select 1 as [I am a column, @novariableshere!]` (which is the same as `select 1 as "I am a column, @novariableshere!"`).

Comment: It works fine for creating contracts.  This goes through with no error/warning and seems to work fine when deployed to the database.  Though, it is a script not SP.

CREATE CONTRACT [@BasicContract] 
      ([@RequestMessageType] 
         SENT BY INITIATOR,
       [@ReplyMessageType] 
         SENT BY TARGET
      );
GO

Comment: I would check the contract name in the database..

Comment: The contract name seems fine.  Is it possible it wasn't extracted with the DACPAC file?  I was hoping to reference them that way vs building it into the Database Project but that may be my only option to get this to compile without warnings assuming that works.

Comment: @NathanChampion, are you certain the contract name is as expected with the variable name specification? I would expect the contract to be named as the variable name, not the value of the variable: `SELECT * FROM sys.service_contracts WHERE name = '@BasicContract';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to import the creation scripts/files into my Visual Studio Database Project to get this all to work properly without giving me syntax errors.

I tried extracting the DACPAC with "Include application-scoped objects only" unchecked and "include extended properties" checked but was still getting the same issues I had before.

I added individual SQL items to my project for messages, services and contracts.  Examples:

Service:

```
CREATE SERVICE [//Web/Queue/InitiatorService]
    ON QUEUE DataQueue;
```

Contract:

```
CREATE CONTRACT [//Web/Queue/BasicContract]
(
    [//Web/Queue/RequestMessage] SENT BY INITIATOR,
    [//Web/Queue/ReplyMessage] SENT BY TARGET
)
```

Message Types:

```
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//Web/Queue/ReplyMessage]
       VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//Web/Queue/RequestMessage]
    VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;
```

That allowed me to conform to the database schema still and avoid future errors.  I *did* still reference the target service with a SQLCMD variable so I can use the same name except for the service in development vs production environments.  Here's my stored procedure for sending messages now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[z_Queue_SendMessage]
    @ProcedureName VARCHAR(1000) = 'Procedure', 
    @SubProcedureName VARCHAR(500) = 'SO', 
    @ProcedureType VARCHAR(200) = 'Delete', 
    @Inserted AS XML = NULL, 
    @Deleted AS XML = NULL
AS


DECLARE @InitDlgHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

DECLARE @RequestMsg NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Message XML;

DECLARE @TargetService NVARCHAR(100) = N'//$(WebDb)/Queue/TargetService'

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN DIALOG @InitDlgHandle
        FROM SERVICE [//Web/Queue/InitiatorService]
        TO SERVICE @TargetService
        ON CONTRACT [//Web/Queue/BasicContract]
        WITH
            ENCRYPTION = OFF;

SET @Message = (SELECT
                ProcedureName    = @ProcedureName,
                SubProcedureName = @SubProcedureName,
                ProcedureType    = @ProcedureType,
                Inserted         = @Inserted,
                Deleted          = @Deleted
            FOR XML PATH('Request'));

SEND ON CONVERSATION @InitDlgHandle
        MESSAGE TYPE [//Web/Queue/RequestMessage]
        (@Message);

SELECT @Message AS SentRequestMsg;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/wqweto/UcsFiscalPrinters/blob/master/contrib/UcsFPHub/db/combined-SQL-Server.sql#L233-L236) works

```
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @Handle
FROM        SERVICE @SvcName
TO          SERVICE @TargetSvc, 'CURRENT DATABASE'
WITH        ENCRYPTION = OFF
```

Try **not** quoting both `@InitiatorService`, `@BasicContract` and `@RequestMessageType` -- this just makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, this does fix compiling issues but not the reference warning from VS.  I either can't reference the service/contract/type or the DACPAC simply doesn't include it.  I've tried playing around with the options for extracting the database schema but still no luck in getting VS to see it as a valid reference.  I think I may have to deploy those all with the Database Project itself.